# change image width and height for div class css

Tags: image

I want to change the width and height of the images on my homepage. I checked with the inspect tool and found out that these images have a `div.post-thumb` class. So is it possible to change the width and height for all images that have this class ?

Comment: Yes, If you have same class name for all tags.

Comment: Can you give a example of how I could do this ?

Comment: Something like this `div.post-thumb{width:100px; height:100px;}`. All div that loads the image has to have the class name `post-thumb`

Comment: check this fiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/mcdstw63/`